# Using Wireguard to route traffic via server

Tags: ubuntu, wireguard

I'd like to use Wireguard on my VPS server to tunnel my http/https traffic and have a fixed IP.

I tried using the tutorial on the Digital Ocean (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-wireguard-on-ubuntu-20-04) but I can't make it work. I installed the Wireguard server properly and on the Desktop as well.

On my server:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
Address = fd24:609a:6c18::1/64
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = ufw route allow in on wg0 out on eth0
PostUp = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip6tables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ufw route delete allow in on wg0 out on eth0
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = ...

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
Endpoint = ...:64619
```

And on my desktop:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.8.0.2/24
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = my server ip:51820
```

(I've hide my server IP).

My client connects with the server, but it seems the traffic through server does not work.

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error come from your `AllowedIPs` settings, here is how to fix it:

Update it `sudo nano /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` then enable the forwarding on your VPS server `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf` then create or uncomment this line `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` then reload sysctl `sudo sysctl -p` then restart `WireGuard` on your `server` and `client`.